# Dictionary of custom objects, how best to sort and display in a SwiftUI view using List and ForEach?

Tags: arrays, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, swiftui-list, swift-dictionary

I have a `customObject` which I store in Firebase's realtime database:

```
struct CustomObject: Codable {
    var id: UUID?
    var name: String?
    var status: String?
}
```

The `customObjects` are stored in a `Dictionary` with `UUID` being the `key`:

[image: Firebase Dictionary Screenshot]

I am able to load the data into a `[String: CustomObject]` `Dictionary` in my iOS application, but I am unsure if my approach to sort and display the `customObjects` using  a `List()` `ForEach(...) {`  is a best practice.

**my current solution is to build an `Array` when the `Dictionary` is loaded**

I use `didSet` everytime the database updates to recreate an `Array` which I can use on the `list()`:

```
class AppManager: ObservableObject {

   @Published var customObjectArray: [CustomObject] = []

   @Published var customObjectDictionary: [String:CustomObject]? {
      didSet {
         if customObjectDictionary != nil {
            customObjectArray = []

            for (key, value) in customObjectDictionary! {
               var tempObject: CustomObject = value
               tempObject.id = UUID(uuidString: key)
               customObjectArray.append(tempObject)
            }

            customObjectArraySort()
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is my `View`:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppManager
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(app.customObjectArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                HStack{
                    Text(app.customObjectArray[index].name ?? "")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(app.customObjectArray[index].status ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am aware that a `Dictionary` is a unordered collection and that attempting to sort based on `customObject.name` in a `list` with a `Dictionary` is unsuitable.

According to Apple's documentation

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and
> values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering. Each
> value is associated with a unique key, which acts as an identifier for
> that value within the dictionary. Unlike items in an array, items in a
> dictionary do not have a specified order. You use a dictionary when
> you need to look up values based on their identifier, in much the same
> way that a real-world dictionary is used to look up the definition for
> a particular word.

Is using `didSet` and making an `Array` from the `Dictionary` of `customObjects` considered a best practice?

Is there a better approach for `sorting` and `listing` `customObjects` from a `Dictionary`?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use a Dictionary for this?

Comment: I am under the impression it is best practice to store a collection of objects in Firebase as a dictionary rather than Array if multiple users might be access and modifying the data at the same time.

Comment: I don't use Firebase, so I can't speak to that.

Answer (score 1):

Turning a `Dictionary` into a `RandomAccessCollection`, to which an `Array` conforms,  is necessary if your want to run it through a ForEach, so this is fine.

Regardless of whether you have a `Dictionary` that you convert to an `Array` as your data source, you shouldn't use `.indices` in this way, especially for something that is easily made `Identifiable`.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: AppManager
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(app.customObjectArray) { object in
                HStack{
                    Text(object.name ?? "")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(object.status ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomObject: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID // Make this non-optional
    var name: String?
    var status: String?
}
```

The way you set it up, if any element is added to, or removed from, the array, you can cause a crash. This means you can't use `.onDelete`, etc. Also, `.onMove` won't work properly either.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please select it as the answer by clicking the checkmark.